# Icomoon Font download error

Tags: php, css

Error getting in website

[image]

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('icon-fonts/icomoon.html');
    src:url('icon-fonts/icomoond41d.html?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('icon-fonts/icomoon-2.html') format('truetype'),
        url('icon-fonts/icomoon-3.html') format('woff'),
        url('icon-fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

How to over come this error?

EDIT:

I have used this code and it don't shows any icon display even in local system

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('icon-fonts/icomoon.eot');
src:url('icon-fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('icon-fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
url('icon-fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('icon-fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Suggest me what to do now?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong syntax.

You're supposed to link to the actual font files...not pages

It should look something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: The same code is working for another site with same as i wrote.